# Список файлов, существовавших в папке

Tags: git, git-log, git-diff

Хочу для папки получить имена всех файлов, существовавших в ней когда-либо.

Годится как вариант за всё время существования репозитория, так и между двумя коммитами. Но если файл был добавлен, а потом удалён между проверяемыми точками (т. е. не входит в diff), то он тоже должен быть в списке.

Поэтому не подходит

```
git diff --name-only 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111 -- .
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6017987/4827341 плюс grep не подойдёт?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, похож, правда придётся немного обработать.

Comment: Так? `git log --name-only --format='' . | sort -u`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, ответ-то будешь писать? Принять, наверное, правильнее другую версию, потому что я так вопрос сформулировал, но реально мне твоя оказалась полезнее.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, `git log --diff-filter=D --summary` - ты ж на это ссылку дал? Я в него добавил `--pretty=oneline`, но после сегодняшнего ответа узнал, что `--format=` лучше. Ну и само собой, путь к каталогу в конец.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, так что, будешь ответ писать, или мне самому?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, ok, написал сам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Список всех файлов в папке с начала времён:

```
git log --no-renames --name-only --format='' . | sort -u
```

Для списка изменённых файлов с коммита `123abc`:

```
git log --no-renames --name-only --format='' 123abc..HEAD . | sort -u
```

Но надо понимать, что в этом списке будут только файлы которые как-то менялись за этот период, т.е. если нужны все файлы, то список надо обьеденить с текущим списком файлов в папке.

Comment: Да, вроде похоже, но мне больше подошёл `git log --format= --diff-filter=D --summary -- .` А вот за `--format=` вместо `--pretty=oneline` спасибо! Только `--format=''` в винде гит не понимает, надо просто на `=` закончить.

Answer (score 1):

- Чтобы получить список коммитов, в которых удалялись файлы, надо выводить `log` с параметром `--diff-filter=D`.
- Чтобы увидеть имена удалённых файлов, надо добавить `--summary`.

  Есть нюанс: иногда имена окажутся в кавычках. В моём случае это какая-то поместь из `\` в пути помимо нормальных `/` - возможно какая-то ошибка при коммите, не знаю.
- Чтобы сделать сообщения о коммитах однострочными, можно использовать `--pretty=oneline`, но можно совсем убрать вывод этих сообщений написав `--format=` (возможно, в случае линукса `--format=''`).

Таким образом получится список всех файлов, кдаления которых были закоммичены в репозиторий (насколько я понимаю, имена могут повторяться если файл удалили, потом добавили, а потом снова удалили):

```
git log --format= --diff-filter=D --summary -- .
```

Чтобы получить список файлов, которые были удалены, но ещё закоммичены, надо из вывода команды

```
git status --porcelain -- .
```

выбрать строки, начинающиеся на  `D`.

Ну а чтобы получить файлы, существующие в папке сейчас, git не нужен.